# Dynamic grid mosaic image layout for personal portfolio using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

First post! I'm trying to make a responsive/dynamic image grid layout for my portfolio. Here's where I'm at:

http://jsfiddle.net/fj5w750t/2/

The prime example of what I would ideally want is what https://www.artstation.com/ has on their front page which means:

- seamless rectangular tiles that keep aspect ratio
- 1x1 tiles (heightXwidth)
- 2x2 tiles
- 1x2 tiles (ideally)
- 2x1 tiles (ideally)
- 2x3 tiles (ideally)
- number of columns changes to fit container width 100%
- tiles scale uniformly to fit column width 100%

Right now my container max width is 960px which makes the 1x1 tile 160x160px, the 2x2 tile 320x320px etc. The way I have it set up right now, is to use twice as many rows (6 at max width) as I want to be 'displayed' where each column is the size of the smallest tile. The idea was to have the tiles with width >=2 occupy more than one column.

What works:

- dynamic number of columns
- scaling images down based on column width

What doesn't work (properly):

- ordering the tiles to occupy the least amount of space
- having tiles with width >= 2 occupy more than one column

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="gallery">
        <li><a href=''><img id='picSML' src='img/160.jpg' style='max-width:160px'></a></li>
        <li><a href=''><img id='picSML' src='img/160.jpg' style='max-width:160px'></a></li>
        <li><a href=''><img id='picMED' src='img/160x320.jpg' style='max-width:320px'></a></li>
        <li><a href=''><img id='picSML' src='img/160.jpg' style='max-width:160px'></a></li>
        <li><a href=''><img id='picSML' src='img/320x160.jpg' style='max-width:160px'></a></li>
        <li><a href=''><img id='picMED' src='img/320.jpg' style='max-width:320px'></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.container {
    background: #101010;
    max-width: 960px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
.gallery {
    line-height: 0;
    -webkit-column-count: 6;
    -webkit-column-gap: 0px;
    -moz-column-count: 6;
    -moz-column-gap: 0px;
    column-count: 6;
    column-gap: 0px;
}
.gallery li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.gallery img {
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#picMed {
    -webkit-column-span: 2;
    column-span: 2;
}
@media (max-width: 960px) {
    .gallery {
        -moz-column-count: 6;
        -webkit-column-count: 6;
        column-count: 6;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 640px) {
    .gallery {
        -moz-column-count: 4;
        -webkit-column-count: 4;
        column-count: 4;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 320px) {
    .gallery {
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Before you go further with using `column-count` for masonry layout be aware that it comes with some bugs such as wrong calculation of items in a last column, or wrapping bottom edges of last items in a row to top of the column container, which will cause you to see box-shadow of elements at the top of container.